# fatal error on std::transform c++

Tags: c++, std, stl-algorithm, catch-unit-test

I'm trying to transform a vector of foo instances to a string but I'm having fatal error on std::transform.

Say `data` has the following value:

```
 [0] 
    [name] = John
    [size] = 3423

 [1] 
    [name] = Joseph
    [size] = 3413
```

Code:

```
struct foo {
    foo(std::string n, size_t s)
            : name(std::move(n)),
              size(s)
    {
    }
    std::string name;
    size_t size;
};

std::string server = "1";
std::vector<std::string> output;
output.reserve(static_cast<unsigned_long>(std::distance(std::begin(data), std::end(data))));

std::transform(std::begin(data),
               std::end(data),
               std::begin(output),
               [&, this](foo const& item){

            std::ostringstream result;
            data << server << ","
                 << item.name << ","
                 << item.size << ";";
            return result.str();
        });
```

While debugging it stops at the line
    `*__result = __unary_op(*_first)` of `tranform` implementation in `stl_algo.h` then goes to FatalConditionHandler of catch test framework. I'm new to both catch testing and std::transform. Can someone explain what might cause the problem and how to solve it? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Should that be `result << server << ...`?

Comment: `std::vector::reserve` doesn't do what you think it does. `resize` is more accurate, but even then you might want to avoid that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've reserved space in `output`, but you've left its size at zero.

You then proceed to write through its `begin` iterator, just as if it had space to hold data.

Then everything goes "boom".

Instead of writing through `std:begin(output)`, consider using `std::back_inserter(output)` as the destination iterator.

You also have one other problem: inside your lambda, you have:

```
        std::ostringstream result;
        data << server << ","
             << item.name << ","
             << item.size << ";";
        return result.str();
```

This looks like a fairly obvious mistake--you undoubtedly intended:

```
        std::ostringstream result;
        result << server << ","
             << item.name << ","
             << item.size << ";";
        return result.str();
```

Personally, I'd probably structure the code somewhat differently. I'd add something like:

```
struct foo {
    std::string name;
    size_t size;

    // new addition:
    friend std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os, foo const &f) { 
        return os << f.name << ',' << f.size;
    }
};
```

...then the lambda in your transform becomes rather simpler:

```
std::ostringstream result;
result << server << "," item;
return result.str();
```

It might, however, be worth considering doing this without the `stringstream` itermediaries at all. In this case, you really just need string concatenation, and they impose quite a bit of overhead to do that.

```
struct foo { 
// ...
    std::string to_string() { 
        return name + "," + size;
    }
};
```

Then the lambda body becomes:

```
return server + "," + item.to_string();
```

Shorter, simpler, and almost certainly faster.

Comment: Thanks a lot!!! This is really helpful!